# Como usar uma função para varias divs em vanilla JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css3

Preciso implementar uma regra apra a badge mudar de cor conforme o "Value" porem a regra só esta pegando a 1 badge as outras não esta pegando como deveria utilziar no meu JavaScript?

```
<nav class="tiles box-one mx-auto d-table w-50 ">
    <div type="button" class="btn tile col-md-2 badge  position-relative">
        <img src="./img/logo_meli.jpg">
        <input id="ValBdg" type="hidden" value="1" />
        <span  class="bdg badge position-absolute badge-notification btn-danger"> 666</span>
    </div>
    
    <div type="button" class="btn tile col-md-2 badge position-relative">
        <img src="./img/logo_meli.jpg">
        <input id="ValBdg" type="hidden" value="2" />
        <span  class="bdg badge position-absolute  badge-notification btn-danger"> 666</span>
        
    </div>

    <div type="button" class="btn tile col-md-2 badge  position-relative" >
        <img src="./img/logo_meli.jpg">
        <input id="ValBdg" type="hidden" value="0" />
        <span  class="bdg badge position-absolute  badge-notification btn-danger"> 666</span>
        
    </div>
</nav>
```

```js
var ValBdg = document.getElementById('ValBdg').value;

function Msg(){
    var nodes = document.getElementsByClassName('bdg');

    for (let x=0, s=nodes.length; x<s; x++){
        nodes[x].classList.add("btn-danger");
    }
}

function NoMsg(){
    var nodes = document.getElementsByClassName('bdg');

    for (let x=0, s=nodes.length; x<s; x++){
        nodes[x].classList.remove("btn-danger");
        nodes[x].classList.add("btn-primary");
    }
}

if(ValBdg > 0 ){
    Msg();
}else{
    NoMsg();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De acordo com a especificação HTML, o atributo `id` **deve** ser único num documento. `getElementById` parte do princípio que isto é verdade e por isso apenas devolve um elemento - o primeiro que encontra do documento com um determinado `id`.

Contudo o atributo `id` não tem necessariamente que ser único (apesar de ser desaconselhado e uma má prática).

Para resolver o seu problema, sugiro as seguintes alterações:

- usar `class` em vez de `id` no `input`;
- utilizar `getElementByClassName` para obter os inputs;
- iterar sobre os inputs e aplicar a lógica que pretende.

Exemplo:

```js
function setBadges() {
  const badgeValues = document.getElementsByClassName('ValBdg');
  
  for (let i = 0; i < badgeValues.length; i++) {
    const badge = badgeValues[i].nextElementSibling;
    const badgeClass = badgeValues[i].value > 0 ? 'badge-danger' : 'badge-primary';
    
    badge.classList.remove('badge-danger', 'badge-primary');
    badge.classList.add(badgeClass);
  }
}

document.getElementById('setBadgesButton').addEventListener('click', setBadges);
```

```css
.badge {
  font-size: 10px;
  padding: 2px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.badge.badge-primary {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.badge.badge-danger {
  color: white;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input class="ValBdg" type="text" value="1" />
  <span class="badge">AAA</span>
</div>

<div>
  <input class="ValBdg" type="text" value="2" />
  <span class="badge">BBB</span>
</div>

<div>
  <input class="ValBdg" type="text" value="0" />
  <span class="badge">CCC</span>
</div>

<button id="setBadgesButton">Set Badges</button>
```

Comment: então eu fiz aqui uma classe chamada "ValBdg", dai fiz 

document.getElementsByClassName('ValBdg');

porem ainda dentro disso preciso pegar o "value", sabe me dizer como faria isso para aplicar a function ?

Comment: Editei a resposta e adicionei um exemplo. Por favor verifique,

Comment: Perfeito cara era justamente isso que eu precisava(editando ele não precisei nem usar o CSS) muito obrigado, eu preferia em JavaScript que tenho mais familiaridade mas vou me familiarizar no JQuery tb. Só mais uma pergunta nos casos em que o Value veio "0" eu gostaria de fazer com que a imagem fique em grayscale , eu achei alguma coisa aqui apenas com CSS não teria como fazer apenas em JS né.

Comment: Ótimo. Se resolveu o problema, por favor assinale esta resposta correta. Eu também prefiro js vanilla mas como o seu código inicial estava em jQuery, respondi em jQuery.